# Tkinter module not being recognized - no module named '_tkinter' error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter

I am using Python 3.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to upload code to an app that interfaces with a robot (Opentrons, OT-1 if relevant), but the app does not accept the code and tells me `ImportError: no module named 'tkinter'`.

When I try to import tkinter into python3.7 in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I have already done `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`, and I tried to `install tk-devel` but it did not work because package was unable to be located. I have also looked into using diff --git as shown on the following link, but I was having issues executing the patch that was given. https://github.com/clearlinux/clr-bundles/issues/65

These are my imports on the program file that is being uploaded to the robot's app

```
from opentrons import robot, containers, instruments
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog
```

I am expecting the app to accept the code and let the robot execute the protocol, and I am also expecting tkinter to be able to be imported when I access python3.7 via the terminal. I AM able to import and pull up the test dialogue box when I import Tkinter into python 2.7.12, AND when I import tkinter into python 3.5.2.

If you want to ask why I have three versions of python - it's a lab computer and I'm not the only one who does not know what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if additional information is needed I am happy to provide.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk` perhaps... You can find that answer about 3.6 here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/815874/importerror-no-named-tkinter-please-install-the-python3-tk-package

Comment: Just did that, had to wade through figuring out why add-apt-repository wasn't working but I managed to fix that and install python3.7-tk......and nothing changed, I am still (oddly enough) receiving the same error message when I try to import tkinter into python3.7 in the terminal

Comment: Did you check the dependencies? For example setuptools?? 
Check this website https://altanalyze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StandAloneDependencies/ may help!

Comment: I have the same issue, along with other import issues. I am using Windows, btw, so this doesn't seem to be a linux specific issue